# "Processing" in Matlab software slowing the program down

Tags: matlab

Whenever I save, change a folder, or sometimes at seemingly random times, the current folder tile will show a loading icon and say "processing"

[image]

I consistently have to press cancel or else the Matlab software will slow down or freeze.  No one else in my programming class seems to be having a problem with this.  I'm using MATLAB_R2015b.  What can I do to stop this from happening?

Comment: How many files do you have in that folder and where are you storing them (HDD/SSD/Cloud)?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft doesn't help him, since he's in a "programming class". Besides, it's a problem I haven't seen before, and since the rest of his class doesn't have it either, the suggestion of switching programming languages is rather useless to him. Might as well suggest python, which is the usual go-to language from MATLAB.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Or to Python, Fortram, C, PHP, ADA, .... Oh wait none of those suggestion make any sense, because "use another programming language" is not an answer to anything! (and please, what is even `<-`??)

Comment: Check your `path` variable, maybe you accidentally added large parts of your HDD. Another possibility would be some backup / cloud synchronisation service which actually writes files to that folders, triggering the updates. Also check hidden folders.

Comment: This is the same issue I experienced with R2015a. And there is also a very long loading when you want to open a file in the Editor. For R2011a, it never happened any of them.

Comment: @AnderBiguri  what: you've never seen a 2-char operator?  Never had to use a language whose assignment opr is `:=` ?    Anyway, so what if it's a programming class.  The *class*, then, should be in R or python, because `Matlab` has grossly inconsistent syntax and ugly object constructions.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft It was just a joke. The important thing here is: going to tags is stackoverflow and recomending people to use another language is probably not the most encouraged behaviour in SO.

Comment: [Probably the same issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35457243/matlab-program-freezes-because-of-sudden-high-resource-processing-without-runn)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with this question in the future, this may be a problem with your source control and how matlab does it. Since I didn't want matlab to perform version control on my code, I just disabled it and CPU issues disappeared! Instructions to disable are in this reply: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/159574-matlab-2014b-on-yosemite-high-cpu