# Matlab - program freezes because of sudden high resource processing without running script

Tags: macos, matlab, save

I'm running Matlab R2015b on my mac with OSX 10.11 El Captain. When starting Matlab, changing the directory in file explorer or when saving a file / running an unsaved file. A yellow processing box appears in the bottom left and Matlab consumes more and more resources. When the process is not canceled Matlab uses more than 400% CPU (low memory usage) and does not react for about 10 minutes or even more. Most times there is no feedback what happend - Today I got following error after start up and the "processing" stuff:

```
Exception in thread "Explorer NavigationContext request queue" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1913)
    at java.util.StringTokenizer.nextToken(StringTokenizer.java:352)
    at com.mathworks.matlab.api.explorer.FileLocation.getTokens(FileLocation.java:268)
    at com.mathworks.matlab.api.explorer.FileLocation.getParent(FileLocation.java:123)
    at com.mathworks.mlwidgets.explorer.model.vfs.VirtualFileSystem.resolveLocation(VirtualFileSystem.java:285)
    at com.mathworks.mlwidgets.explorer.model.vfs.VirtualFileSystem.getTarget(VirtualFileSystem.java:276)
    at com.mathworks.mlwidgets.explorer.model.vfs.VirtualFileSystem.resolveLocation(VirtualFileSystem.java:285)
    at com.mathworks.mlwidgets.explorer.model.vfs.VirtualFileSystem.getTarget(VirtualFileSystem.java:276)
    at com.mathworks.mlwidgets.explorer.model.vfs.VirtualFileSystem.resolveLocation(VirtualFileSystem.java:285)
    at com.mathworks.mlwidgets.explorer.model.vfs.VirtualFileSystem.getTarget(VirtualFileSystem.java:276)
    at com.mathworks.mlwidgets.explorer.model.vfs.VirtualFileSystem.resolveLocation(VirtualFileSystem.java:285)
    at com.mathworks.mlwidgets.explorer.model.vfs.VirtualFileSystem.getTarget(VirtualFileSystem.java:276)
    at com.mathworks.mlwidgets.explorer.model.vfs.VirtualFileSystem.isMountPoint(VirtualFileSystem.java:239)
    at com.mathworks.mlwidgets.explorer.model.vfs.VirtualFileSystem.toExternalEntry(VirtualFileSystem.java:324)
    at com.mathworks.mlwidgets.explorer.model.vfs.VirtualFileSystem.toExternalEntry(VirtualFileSystem.java:319)
    at com.mathworks.mlwidgets.explorer.model.vfs.VirtualFileList$MountingReceiver.receive(VirtualFileList.java:101)
    at com.mathworks.mlwidgets.explorer.model.vfs.VirtualFileList$MountingReceiver.receive(VirtualFileList.java:90)
    at com.mathworks.util.AsyncReceiverUtils$3.receive(AsyncReceiverUtils.java:77)
    at com.mathworks.mlwidgets.explorer.model.realfs.StatToEntryAdapter.receive(StatToEntryAdapter.java:55)
    at com.mathworks.mlwidgets.explorer.model.realfs.StatToEntryAdapter.receive(StatToEntryAdapter.java:16)
    at com.mathworks.util.NativeJava.listFiles(Native Method)
    at com.mathworks.mlwidgets.explorer.model.realfs.RealFileList.readFilesAndFolders(RealFileList.java:50)
    at com.mathworks.mlwidgets.explorer.model.overlayfs.OverlayFileList.readFilesAndFolders(OverlayFileList.java:42)
    at com.mathworks.mlwidgets.explorer.model.vfs.VirtualFileList.readFilesAndFolders(VirtualFileList.java:52)
    at com.mathworks.mlwidgets.explorer.model.table.UiFileList.readAndUpdateCache(UiFileList.java:358)
    at com.mathworks.mlwidgets.explorer.model.table.UiFileList.access$500(UiFileList.java:43)
    at com.mathworks.mlwidgets.explorer.model.table.UiFileList$6.run(UiFileList.java:323)
    at com.mathworks.util.RequestQueue.execute(RequestQueue.java:129)
    at com.mathworks.util.RequestQueue.access$000(RequestQueue.java:25)
    at com.mathworks.util.RequestQueue$2.run(RequestQueue.java:79)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Maybe you added a folder with looping [symbolic links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) or similar stuff which causes it to loop infinite? I would contact the support, just from the stack without having the code it is difficult to tell what's going wrong.

Comment: [I would guess this is the same issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35157480/processing-in-matlab-software-slowing-the-program-down)